# Use php variables in a href

Tags: php

I'm creating a Twitter share button for the website that I'm working at. I want a few pre-set share texts, which I want to load with `php`. I'm struggling with the `variables` in the `href`.

I've in one document the html code for the share buttons.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="<?php echo $twitter ?>">
          <div class="socials twitter">
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="<?php echo $facebook ?>">
          <div class="socials facebook">
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="<?php echo $youtube ?>">
          <div class="socials youtube">
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <a href="<?php echo $instagram ?>">
          <div class="socials instagram">
          </div>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I import that part in the `index.php` where I want the social buttons with:

```
<?php 
  $twitter= file_get_contents('attributes/twitter-share-currentBand.php');
  $facebook='';
  $youtube='';
  $instagram='';
  include 'partials/socials.php'; 
?>
```

The file that I call in the twitter variable looks like this:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Bekijk%20<?php echo $bandName ?>%20op%20<?php echo $currentURL ?>!
```

The variable that I use in this document are set in the `index.php`. The problem is that the `php` code shows up as text and doesn't shows the variable. This is the url that I get from it:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Bekijk%20%3C?php%20echo%20$bandName%20?%3E%20op%20%3C?php%20echo%20$currentURL%20?%3E!
```

## Edit 1

I'm now using

```
$twitter= include('attributes/twitter-share-currentBand.php');
```

and that is working. The new problem is that the include isn't load on the right place. This is how the code looks if I look at the source code of the page.

```
 https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Bekijk%20Something like Sunshine%20op%20!
 <div class="row segment-sub mod-block">
   <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="1">
          <div class="socials twitter">
          </div>
      </a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Either the view script you're running is a HTML file (needs to be .phtml) or your PHP isn't parsing correctly.

Comment: why are you reading a PHP file content into variable? you should include the file

Comment: @bansi I tried the include the file, but it didn't work. So you suggest that instead of 'file_get_contents('file.php'); I should use something else?

Comment: HTML stickler: You should place the href inside the div and not the other way around. That could have some pretty strange side effects.

Comment: I'm also having trouble wrapping my head around all this. Do all files bear the `.php` extension, or is one or more are `.html`? and are you running this off a webserver with php installed? running as `http://localhost` (or hosted) or as `file:///` directly into your browser?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, all files have `.php` as extension. I'm running it local with `valet`, so I use `urlfrompage.dev/`. I have the `a` around the `div` because the `div` gets content with a `::before`.

Comment: you'll need to include all your `.php` files and the content in another edit with  their respective names above the code. This question isn't getting getting any final solutions. Right now, it's hard to say what the files are, their names and their exact contents. If some of them don't have an opening `<?php` tag, then you would get "code" that would appear, rather than being parsed.

Comment: btw, the "1" that you see, means the file was successfully found. It also means that the content wasn't properly retrieved.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's working now. Thanks for your help. Would it still be convenient if I added my full code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not read the file contents to the variable. you should actually `include` the file. comment added in code

try

```
ob_start(); //start output buffering
// no include your file this actually outputs the parsed variable and you
// capture it in optput buffer
include('attributes/twitter-share-currentBand.php');
$twitter= ob_get_clean(); //store the output to the variable and stop output buffering.
```

`file_get_contents` reads the contents of the file as it is and puts in the variable `$twitter` when you actually want the parsed value of `attributes/twitter-share-currentBand.php`

You should use output buffering as your `attributes/twitter-share-currentBand.php` actually outputs the value you required to store in variable.

Note: `$bandName` and `$currentURL` should be initialized before including the file.

**Edit:** Alternatively you can include the file directly instead of storing the output to a variable. like following.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
    <a href="<?php include('attributes/twitter-share-currentBand.php') ?>">
        <div class="socials twitter">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, the php variables are working now. Thanks! Only the code isn't included at the right place. The code is above the a tag and the href has 1 in it. href="1". And yes, I'm echo-ing the variable in the href, see the first part of my question.

Comment: ok my first answer was wrong. please check the corrected answer.

Comment: This works, thanks! And from you comments in the code I understand that I can start a second `ob-start()` after the first `ob_get_clean();`, right? Because it stops output buffering.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can write like in php

<?php 
$url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $url;?>">PHP 5 Tutorial</a>

Or for PHP 5.4+ (<?= is the PHP short echo tag):
<a href="<?= $url ?>">PHP 5 Tutorial</a>

or 
echo '<a href="' . $url . '">PHP 5 Tutorial</a>';
```

Comment: I've the example that you give working, but I want to use a `variable` in the `$url`.

Comment: if you want to get variable from session then write like this $_SESSION['url'] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/';                                     <?php $url = _SESSION['url'];?>                                                                      <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

Comment: if you want to get variable from session try                            $_SESSION['url'] = 'https://www.w3schools.com/php/';                                                       $url = $_SESSION['url'];                                                                          if you want get current page url in php try -                                         $url = <?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?> OR                                  $url = <?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a idea why the include doesn't work? I updated my question

Comment: please tell me what is error display so i can help you. or give me more description about error or scenario. for checking the error write below code on the top of the page                                                                  <?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: If above comment & answer is usefull to you, then please checkmark the      if you are satisfied above the answer or comments then please make it true. Thank you.